# LilyPond: Analysis Brackets over 1 note or in conjunction with other functions

Tags: lilypond

IIUC, the way you notate analysis brackets in LilyPond is `a\startGroup b\stopGroup`.

For my use-case, this is inconvenient in a couple ways.

1. Sometimes I need a bracket on just one note. `a\startGroup\stopGroup` results in no brackets rendered and a compiler complaint:

```
do not have that many brackets
conflicting note group events
```

2. I have some functions to make writing common grace notes easier. When used with those, the group start is unable to attach to the grace note, so the bracket ends up in the wrong place (on the main note), which I've only been able to resolve with some suboptimal workarounds.

Is it possible to define a custom bracket type that operates more like `\bracket { <musicgroup> }`, and just places the bracket over the given music group? I think this would solve both my problems, but don't know how to go about it.

Here is a sample score showing what I want the bracket to look like, generally. `lgrchip` approaches the syntax I'd like, but is limited -- it only works if the first note is a below-the-line grace note.

```
\version "2.22.1"

#(define scottish-snare '(
  (snare          default #f   1)
  (acousticsnare  default #f  -1)
  (sidestick      cross   #f   1)
  (hisidestick    cross   #f  -1)
))
drumPitchNames.rs = #'snare
drumPitchNames.ls = #'acousticsnare
drumPitchNames.rx = #'sidestick
drumPitchNames.lx = #'hisidestick

\layout {
  indent = 0
  \context {
    \DrumVoice
    \consists "Horizontal_bracket_engraver"
    % Set up chip notation.
    \override HorizontalBracket.direction = #UP
    \override HorizontalBracket.staff-padding = #5
    \override HorizontalBracket.bracket-flare = #'(0 . 0)
    \override HorizontalBracket.edge-height = #'(2 . 2)
    \override HorizontalBracketText.parent-alignment-X = #-1
    \override HorizontalBracketText.X-offset = #1
    \override HorizontalBracketText.Y-offset = #-2
    \override HorizontalBracketText.direction = #DOWN
    \override HorizontalBracketText.text = "u."

    % Other useful configuration
    \override Beam.positions = #'(-4 . -4)
    \stemDown
  }
}

rflam = #(define-music-function (dur) (ly:duration?)
  #{ \drummode { \slashedGrace ls8 rs$dur } #})
lflam = #(define-music-function (dur) (ly:duration?)
  #{ \drummode { \slashedGrace rs8 ls$dur } #})
lgrchip = #(define-music-function (music) (ly:music?)
  #{ \drummode { \slashedGrace ls8\startGroup $music \stopGroup } #})
lgrchip = #(define-music-function (music) (ly:music?)
  #{ \drummode { \slashedGrace rs8\startGroup $music \stopGroup } #})

\drums {
  \set DrumStaff.drumStyleTable = #(alist->hash-table scottish-snare)
  \override Staff.StaffSymbol.line-count = #1
  \time 2/4

  \rflam8-> rs8:32( ls) rs8:32( |
  ls) rs16.-> ls32 rs16. 32 ls8 |
  
  \lgrchip { rs8-> rs8:32( ls) rs8:32( | ls) rs16.-> ls32 rs16. 32 ls8 | 
  \break \rflam8-> }
  rs4:32( 8) | 8 8 8 8 
}
```

Side note: I am currently using version 2.22 because that is what `apt install` found. I may update manually once I decide this software is going to work for my use-case.